# Netsuite as an Identity Provider - Ping (SAML 2.0)

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, netsuite, pingfederate

I'm attempting to implement SSO and wanted to use Netsuite as an IdP. Now I know officially this isn't possible but I was wondering if it's even remotely possible to have something like this done (custom coded or anything like that)?

Unfortunately I am not the most knowledgeable person in regards to these things, please forgive my ignorance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really comes down to what NetSuite exposes for PingFederate to hook into.  From a PingFederate perspective, if NetSuite exposes the ability to validate an existing user session by a 3rd Party or provides an API that can essentially authenticate a user you could create a custom IDP Adapter for PF that would handle this.

This is something that your Ping Account team can assist with if you're interested in getting some assistance.

HTH
--Ian (Note: I work for Ping)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the insight Ian! I guess I may need to contact Netsuite and get a bit more information on what it can do in regards to external authentication. I really appreciate the response.